# Exponential Probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

People getting to a builduing in time gaps that distribute exponential, in 3 people per minute rate.

let X be the rate of people that entering the building.
X~exponential(3).

What is the probability for the 3rd person to get to the building in less than 3 minutes after the 1st one?

Comment: Hint : Use Memoryless Property.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta$ be the exponential parameter, which is 3 in this example.

The first person doesn't matter; this is equivalent to asking for the probability that the second person gets into the building within 3 minutes of it opening.

Assuming that people enter independently, if $X$ and $Y$ are both $\mathrm{Exp}(\theta)$ then $X + Y = \mathrm{Erlang}(2, \theta)$. See the [Erlang Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) for more details.

So we need $Pr(X+Y \leq 3)$, which will reduce in this case to solving

$$
\int_0^3 \theta^2xe^{-\theta x} dx
$$

which I calculated as around 99.88% from [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolfr.am/XtdSyt).